# add when article in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have table **article**:

```
arrtno     descr         unit   sales
  1        beer            1     10
  2        coke            1     12
  3        beer ct        12      5
  4        coke ct        12      7
```

and a table **mutations**

```
artno   mutation
  1         3  
  2         4
```

I need to query sales for beer so it would be `1*10 + 12*5`. So how to get mutation par from other table and add it to basic item.

Comment: can you give an example of your output?  I am not understanding the last line at all. . . are you looking for a join on the two tables and then do mutations.mutation + article.sale???

Comment: Do you need recursion for the mutations to be done? i.e. when your mutations table also contains tuple `(3,1337)` do you need article record with artno 1337 also be considered as child for artno 1 and therefore be added, too? (since there is mutation chain `1->3->1337`) When yes, then we need your Oracle version and pray you've 10g or higher.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT SUM(unit * sales) FROM article WHERE arrtno IN (    
    SELECT mutation from mutations WHERE artno IN (
        SELECT arrtno FROM article WHERE descr = 'beer'
    )
    UNION
    SELECT arrtno FROM article WHERE descr = 'beer'
)
```

Comment: Actually, I have many items, not just beer so i would need something like: SELECT artno, ( sales*unit + sales of mutation pair(s) * unit of mutation pair(s) ) FROM article

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT b1.unit * b1.sales + b2.unit*b2.sales
 FROM beer b1, beer b2, mutation
 WHERE b1.artno = mutation.artno
 AND b2.artno = mutation.mutation
```